# if/else with setInterval auto-refreshing and on click refreshing event jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Struggling to get this to work properly...Making an if/else statement with setInterval that `if` class is clicked, content refreshes, `else` content auto refreshes after a specific time period.  This is what I have for just auto refreshing atm (which works perfectly):

```
var auto_refreshContentTwo = setInterval (
    function() {
        $('.page_loading_r_content_two_overlay').fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../../path/to/page.php',
            success: function(html) {
                var myContentTwoContent = $('#refreshContentTwo').html(html).find('#refreshContentTwo2');
                $('#refreshContentTwo').html(myContentTwoContent);
            }
        });
    }, 495000
);
```

What I've tried to get a "click" function added, but doesn't do anything...:

```
$('.contentTwoClicked').on('click', function() {
    var refreshClicked = true;
    if(refreshClicked) {
        alert('clicked');
        $('.page_loading_r_content_two_overlay').fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../../path/to/page.php',
            success: function(html) {
                var myContentTwoContent = $('#refreshContentTwo').html(html).find('#refreshContentTwo2');
                $('#refreshContentTwo').html(myContentTwoContent);
            }
        });
    } else {
        var auto_refreshContentTwo = setInterval (
            function() {
                $('.page_loading_r_content_two_overlay').fadeIn();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../../path/to/page.php',
                    success: function(html) {
                        var myContentTwoContent = $('#refreshContentTwo').html(html).find('#refreshContentTwo2');
                        $('#refreshContentTwo').html(myContentTwoContent);
                    }
                });
            }, 495000
        );
    }
});
```

Where am I going wrong?  Or am I way off-base here...?  Any guidance/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you add the html as well

Comment: Lets look at your logic. You want something to happen when the "class" is not clicked. You also want something when the "class" is clicked. Therefore, why is your "auto" code inside the click event handler?

Comment: @GetSet, I'm not sure what you mean here...the `auto_refreshContentTwo` code is in the else statement which I thought occurs if the click event is not clicked...?

Comment: Use `$(document).on('.contentTwoClicked','click', function() { ... });` like this. Because you're appending new HTML content after page load.

Comment: Are you refreshing the entire page, or specific nodes?

Comment: @Hybrid an event does not have an "opposite" event state. It either happens or it doesnt. You could create the opposite thru some sort of state flags or such, easy enough. But then you'd need your own idle loop hence your setInterval logic. But in your case, your idle is set too long. Such checks should be a short interval where you check state to do the auto update.

Comment: @PavlosKaralis, refreshing specific nodes...I do not want to refresh the entire page...I have several of these `auto_refresh` events being fired at different intervals but I'd like to add a `click` handler on each one to `refresh` just that container that the user clicked on all the while the others still auto refresh (unless clicked on of course)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a conditional statement, but rather a variable to store the set interval in so that it can be cleared and restarted on manual refresh via a calling function:

```
//variable to store the setInterval
let refreshInterval = '';

//function that calls setInterval
const autoRefresh = () => {
  refreshInterval = setInterval(()=> { 
    refresh();
    console.log("auto");
  },3000)
}

//run setInterval function on page load; 
autoRefresh();

//manual refresh function
const manualRefresh = () => {
  //erases the setInterval variable
  clearInterval(refreshInterval);
  refresh();
  //then recalls it to reset the countdown
  autoRefresh();
  console.log("manual");
}

//for visual purposes
let refreshCount = 0; 

//node refresher function
const refresh = () => {
    const container = document.getElementById("refresh");
    refreshCount ++; 
    container.textContent= "This div will be refreshed"+ ` Refresh Count: ${refreshCount}`; 
}
```

```
<button onclick="manualRefresh()">Click to Refresh </button>

<div id="refresh">This div will be refreshed</div>
```

See it in action: https://codepen.io/PavlosKaralis/pen/rNxzZjj?editors=1111

Edit: Applied to your code I think it would be:

```
let interval; 

var autoRefresh = () => {
  interval = setInterval (
  function() {
      $('.page_loading_r_content_two_overlay').fadeIn();
      $.ajax({
          url: '../../path/to/page.php',
          success: function(html) {
              var myContentTwoContent = $('#refreshContentTwo').html(html).find('#refreshContentTwo2');
              $('#refreshContentTwo').html(myContentTwoContent);
          }
      });
  }, 495000);
}

$('.contentTwoClicked').on('click', function() {
  
  clearInterval(interval);
  
  alert('clicked');
  $('.page_loading_r_content_two_overlay').fadeIn();
  $.ajax({
      url: '../../path/to/page.php',
      success: function(html) {
          var myContentTwoContent = $('#refreshContentTwo').html(html).find('#refreshContentTwo2');
          $('#refreshContentTwo').html(myContentTwoContent);
      }
  });

  autoRefresh(); 

});

autoRefresh();
```

Comment: I'll give this a try - from your demo, that is exactly what I'm looking for...I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect how it would be applied to your code, though can't check for certain since I don't have the full code.

Comment: @PavlosKaralis i'll comment since i think OP may be missing the crucial point. As per your explanation, the timer *should* be stopped and restarted so the auto doesn't happen during the manual. However, two functions doing the same thing won't really matter since the refresh will happen again in time anyway. But it would be good practice. This however doesn't prevent the reverse: the auto already in progress when a click event comes in. The code design itself to rid out that area, is likely flawed on OP

Comment: @PavlosKaralis, So far signs are good that things are working as intended!  Still testing a few things out just to be sure.  Once all testing is done and all works, I'll mark your answer as solved.  I did have to change some things such as: `interval = setTimout {` that you have is a typo, but even with `setTimeout`, things didn't quite work as intended so changed it to `setInterval`.

Comment: I also needed to implement what @GhanuBha stated in his comment on my question, but that too was a bit off - changed it from `$(document).on('.contentTwoClicked','click', function() { ... });` to `$(document).on('click', '.contentTwoClicked', function() { ... });` and was implemented where we had `$('.contentTwoClicked').on('click', function() {` as content is dynamically added and/or moved...

Comment: Yes that was a typo, should have been setInterval

Comment: Also @GetSet, the timer clears out with `clearInterval(interval)` making it restart once dynamic content is loaded if clicked, and if not clicked, the timer is based on the `autoRefresh()` variable.  So far, with all the testing I've done, everything seems to be working perfectly!  Unless I'm still missing something?

Comment: @Hybrid had mentioned you wont see any noticeable difference, except some additional traffic over the network. You can test this by inserting `console.log()`s in your code for when events get triggered and also on your handlers. No biggie. But imagine if a lot of data was being refreshed. Then it might become of some concern. Or when you have code where state is important on frontend vars.